# # /usr/bin/ld -libmysqlclient /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -libmysqlclient

Tags: linux

```
# /usr/bin/ld -lmysqlclient --verbose
[...]
[attempt to open] /usr/i686-redhat-linux/lib32/libmysqlclient.so [failed] 
tentativo di aprire /usr/i686-redhat-linux/lib32/libmysqlclient.a non riuscito
tentativo di aprire /usr/local/lib32/libmysqlclient.so non riuscito
tentativo di aprire /usr/local/lib32/libmysqlclient.a non riuscito
tentativo di aprire /lib32/libmysqlclient.so non riuscito
tentativo di aprire /lib32/libmysqlclient.a non riuscito
tentativo di aprire /usr/lib32/libmysqlclient.so non riuscito
tentativo di aprire /usr/lib32/libmysqlclient.a non riuscito
tentativo di aprire /usr/i686-redhat-linux/lib/libmysqlclient.so non riuscito
tentativo di aprire /usr/i686-redhat-linux/lib/libmysqlclient.a non riuscito
tentativo di aprire /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.so non riuscito
tentativo di aprire /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.a non riuscito
tentativo di aprire /lib/libmysqlclient.so non riuscito
tentativo di aprire /lib/libmysqlclient.a non riuscito
tentativo di aprire /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so non riuscito
tentativo di aprire /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.a non riuscito
/usr/bin/ld: impossibile trovare -lmysqlclient
```

But i have

```
# locate libmysqlclient
/usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.a
/usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so
/usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18
/usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18.1.0
/usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.a
/usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so
/usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so.18
/usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so.18.1.0
```

how may I fix things? Note, `ld` is called during a rmp rebuild, and I need to be sure that it finds libmysqlclient.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following flag,

```
-L/usr/lib/mysql
```

I think.

(It will instruct ld to look for libraries in the directory `/usr/lib/mysql`, which is where mysql is installed, but is not in the default search pat of ld.)

Comment: I fixed by a symlink /usr/lib/ to /usr/lib/mysql. I am not  sure where to add your flag. Thks anyway.

Comment: The flag should be added to the `ld` invocation `# /usr/bin/ld -lmysqlclient --verbose -L/usr/lib/mysql`